# Only I am able to save a macro-enabled workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

All, I have created a workbook that has some macros in it to import data.  The idea is that the file is a master file, and every time you import data with it, it is **supposed to** place that data on the end of the existing data, and then you save it and move on.

The problem is, I am the **only** user that can save the workbook.  Now, two of the sheets in my workbook I have protected, so that they cannot be edited.  I have done this so that nothing can accidentally be removed (buttons, instructions, notes, etc).  My users have agreed that this protection is a good thing.

But what I think is happening is our network is making anyone who didn't author this file open it as Read Only, and then they cannot save to it.  I first thought maybe if added a save macro (and command button) that it would fix it.  No dice.

Next, I had the workbook unprotect, and then re-protect itself when the user clicks the save button.  Nope, still opening as Read Only.

I then put code in the `Workbook_Open()` Sub that changed it from Read Only to Read Write.  This caused a box to popup when opening the sheet that said the file was in use by "Another User," and it was locked for editing.

The last thing I tried was adding the other users as Authors to the workbook.  And it **STILL** opens as a Read Only file.

I think this has to do with the network settings here in our office (well, corporate-wide, but anyway).  These are policies that cannot be changed.  Can anyone help me find a work-around that allows my sheets to be locked for editing, but allows my users to save to my workbook?

You can see here that I have added three other users as Authors of the file (This is the information page of the file as opened by a user.):
[image: Image showing information page of file as opened on a user's computer]

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue was not related at all to the workbook...

When attempting to Save As in the folder where the workbook was located, we found out that the user I was using for the tests simply did not have write permissions to the folder in question.  I had write permissions to it based on a previous assignment.

So much frustration over something so simple.